# finding unanswered new questions

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, filtering

When I filter for one tag, then I see all the questions orderd by last activity. But most of them are answered.

So I want to filter for the unanswered ones. But when I click “Unanswered” at the top, then they are not ordered by timestamp anymore, but after votes.

How do I find unanswered questions for a selected tag ordered by the timestamp?

Comment: Needs some trickery http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%23?sort=newest&pageSize=50

Comment: On the SE filter page you can create a custom filter and the result there has a *no answer* tab as well. See [this answer how to create a custom filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224557/158100)

Comment: and where is the SE filter page? I feel a bit noob now. I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: maybe my reputation is too low to have a filter page?

Comment: Huh.. hold on...let me check... can you reach this: http://stackexchange.com/filters/new  this should be the root http://stackexchange.com/filters

Comment: the first page not found, the second ask me to sign up. I guess that's a no.

Comment: This is your SE account page http://stackexchange.com/users/3527935/easterbunnybugsmasher

Comment: ok, I edited a filter for java tags on stackoverflow. But when I go to stackoverflow, I can't find this filter anywhere. ...but now I'm completely confused about my SO, SE, Meta SO, Meta SE accounts

Comment: That filter stays on SE and you have to access it from there. And i admit all those sites can be a little overwhelming...Does [this new unaswered java questions](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java?tab=newest) do the trick for you?

Comment: yes, that link is good. I guess the best way is to just bookmark it.

Comment: but I must say it's quite disappointing that I can't have filters on SO without clicking my way through a few SE pages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible without the need to fumble with the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) in the address bar.

Steps to get the newest unanswered question for your tag:

In the search field, enter the tags you want to search on:

- [java] [jvm]
- hit enter
- notice the address bar is now

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+jvm

- In the address-bar replace *questions* with *unanswered*

> https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java+jvm

- Click the tab *newest*

> https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java+jvm?tab=newest

You now have a list of unanswered questions (in SE terms this means questions without an upvoted answer), newest first in your selected tags.

Another possibility is to use a filter on https://stackexchange.com/filters.

Comment: This searches for hits containing both tags.  If you want answers with either tag, just use " or " instead of "+".  But this is exactly what I was looking for, not sure why SO made it so difficult...

Comment: Does this still work? When I try the last url variant, with `unanswered`, I get some questions which have answers.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn unanswered in SE terms means: no upvoted answers (and there is always caching involved)

Answer (score 1):

I did with this url (you need replace with real **tag name** which you are interested)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bTAG%5d%20answers%3a0

So if you need list latest **java** unanswered questions, the url is

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjava%5d%20answers%3a0